# How would i track Incoming SMS in Android?

Tags: android

I am developing an Application and want to track the incoming SMS messages. I need a sample code or routine which I can use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you implement a BroadCast Receiver for Incoming SMS in that case following is the code which will track your imcoming SMS and will give you the Message and Sender Number.

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.gsm.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        //---get the SMS message passed in---
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String str = "";            
        if (bundle != null)
        {
            //---retrieve the SMS message received---
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
            for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
                str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();                     
                str += " :";
                str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                str += "\n";        
            }
            //---display the new SMS message---
            Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }                         
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP didn't ask about sending SMS.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)

Code is in the first answer on this question:

[In android how should i get phone number of sms sender?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692354/in-android-how-should-i-get-phone-number-of-sms-sender)