# get sent and receiving time for incoming SMS

Tags: android, sms, android-contentprovider

Here i am using BroadcastReceiver for Reading incoming SMS.

```
 @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        try {
            if (bundle != null) {
                final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                assert pdusObj != null;
                for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {
                    SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                    String senderNum = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                    String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();
                    Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: " + senderNum + "; message: " + message);

                    Intent myIntent = new Intent("sms_received");
                    myIntent.putExtra("message", message);
                    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(myIntent);
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" + e);

        }
    }
```

how can i get sent and received time of SMS from this.

Answer (score 0):

Part of your question was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9931329/android-get-date-and-time-from-incoming-sms).

To get send time you have to use getTimestampMillis() method.

```
Calendar sendTime = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(smsMessage.getTimestampMillis());

int date = sendTime.get(CALENDAR.DATE);
int hour = sendTime.get(CALENDAR.HOUR_OF_DAY);
// etc...
```

To get receive time use System.currentTimeMillis().

```
Calendar receiveTime = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

int date = receiveTime.get(CALENDAR.DATE);
int hour = receiveTime.get(CALENDAR.HOUR_OF_DAY);
// etc...
```