# Getting reply to a particular sms sent pragmatically from app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, broadcastreceiver, smsmanager

I'm working on an app that requires to read the reply of a particular sms message sent and update the Database, i know i can use SmsManager (Pending Intent) class to know the status of the message (Like SENT or DELIVERED) and also broadcast receiver for receiving sms but i want to be able to read the user reply to that sms.
There can be multiple message sent at a particular time which i want to be able to differentiate between response for each sms.
Is there a way to attach something like an id to sms and get it back when i receive the reply or how can i achieve this? most of the tutorials online only cover how to listen to the status and how to receive new sms.

Comment: I think you want to know the sender and message content of an incoming SMS
[link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378328/android-how-to-get-phone-number-from-a-incoming-sms
[link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007332/how-to-read-the-message-content-of-a-new-in-coming-message-in-android

Comment: There can be multiple message to a single smsAddress, i nee d to know which of the message he is replying to @RameesThattarath

Comment: I dont think there is a one to one mapping between SMSes in android, all SMSs from same address are considered similar

Comment: Nope, you can't really do that. It's not just Android. SMS is a stateless protocol. There's nothing that relates one particular message to another, other than the address. That is, you can't know if a user is replying to a specific message; only that they're sending to a given number.

Comment: Good @MikeM. i will look for other alternative