# Possible to find out if an SMS was sent from phone or web

Tags: android, sms

I'm writing an app to provide a UI to my SMS text messages. One thing my phone doesn't have is the ability to indicate whether the incoming/outgoing message was sent from my phone or from the web? Is this possible to figure out from the SMS's in my inbox/outbox?

H.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692354/in-android-how-should-i-get-phone-number-of-sms-sender He shows how to get the originating number (look for `str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();`), if it is from a web address I think this returns a weird, non-phone number, value.

Comment: Thanks zgc7009, the only difference I can tell from the originating address is that the phone number prefix has +1858 when sent from my phone and 001858 when sent from the web account on my providers website. I guess this wouldn't really be indication enough. There's no specific application code I guess?

Comment: I don't think there is an exact what to say "this message came from that location". There may be some tweaks or weird work-around that would let you narrow down the possibilities but outside of something with the originating address I don't really know.

Comment: thank you for your help ZGC I'll keep looking.